Socket duplication when forking a process in C
I'm learning network programming and trying to implement a HTTP server. I'm following a guide on socket programming in C (https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/split/client-server-background.html) and came across this example:
while(1) {  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
        s, sizeof s);
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

    if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
        close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
        if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
        close(new_fd);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
}

The part I am confused about is the forking of processes.
Why do we close the original socket file descriptor (sockfd) when it was only created in the original parent process? Or more generaly, are all of the resources created by the parent process duplicated in the child - as for example the socket file?

If socket descriptors weren't duplicated into the child process, then forking a child to handle the new connection couldn't work in the first place. Right?

Because sockfd is a server socket which is used only for accepting connections. Child process doesn't need it to communicate to client.

The file descriptors are duplicated in the same kind of way that dup() duplicates a file descriptor, except that fork() does not change the values of the file descriptors. A file descriptor is identified by the combination of its number and the process it belongs to. The file descriptors refer to the underlying file that was originally opened or socket or pipe that was originally created. The underlying open file description or socket or pipe is not released or destroyed until all the file descriptors that refer to it have been closed.

Okay, so multiple file descriptors can be created in parallel "without really affecting one another" - at least in this case where one pending connection is accepted. Thanks everyone for the comments.

@VanjaStojanović Think about file descriptor as an index in a per-process table of references to kernel objects. Different processes may reference different objects by the same index in their tables. Different entries in the same table may reference to the same kernel object (e.g. after dup()). After fork() the table is "copied" the same way as other process memory.

Makes sense, I didn't think about it like that, thanks for the insight :)

Because according to the POSIX specification of fork().

The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's file descriptors [...].

The spirit behind fork() is that process resources are duplicated although this is not 100% true as threads aren't duplicated.

Got it, so it's not only a duplicated pointer pointing to the same resource, rather a completely new resource. Thanks.
